# Can one explicitely construct a sequence of functions of compact support approximating $u\in W_{0}^{1,p}(\Omega)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

We define $W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega)$ as the closure of $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ in the $W^{1,p}$-norm (or equivalently as the closure of the $W^{1,p}$-functions with compact support). Given $u\in W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega)$, we know by definition that there exists a sequence of functions of compact support, that are in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and converge to $u$. Is it possible to explicitely construct such a sequence?

My first thought was to use standard convolution arguments, but it doesn't seem to work that easy.

Comment: please, consider including your work in the question

Comment: Standard convolution arguments give you smooth functions, but they might not be compactly supported.  So multiply by smooth cutoff functions.

Comment: Giovanni: thanks, I didn't think of that.
I basically tried what Nate Eldredge suggests. I Multiplied by a smooth cutoff function and used a mollifier to gain a function that is compactly supported and smooth. The thing is that I didn't find a way to correctly cutoff. I can't prove that the cut and mollified function is close to $u$ outside of the set where the cutoff function is equal to 1. The main problem is that I can't control the gradient of the cut function outside of that set.

Comment: If I recall correctly (and it's been a while) you can do this by exhausting $\Omega$ by a sequence of open sets $\Omega_k\subset \bar{\Omega_k}\subset\Omega_{k+1}\subset \Omega$ such that $\cup \Omega_k = \Omega$ and the closure of each $\Omega_k$ is compact. You can then mollify on $\Omega_k$ with support in $\Omega_{k+1}$ and use a diagonal sequence argument.